# VS2022: Operation Failed: Downloading Android Emulator v31.2.9

Tags: visual-studio-2022

- "The process cannot access the file [C:\Users\A\AppData\Local\Temp\xamarin-android-sdk\emulator-windowsx64-8316981.zip' because it is being used by another process".

This shows whenever I repair Android SDK Tools, everything else installs fine.